# How do I know how many iterations are left in a parfor loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am running a parfor loop in Matlab that takes a lot of time and I would like to know how many iterations are left. How can I get that info?

Comment: You could create N empty text files called 'iter_1', 'iter_2' etc, and delete the corresponding file at the end of each parfor iteration. Then all you need to do is count the number of files in the directory.

Comment: @Jonas, that is disgusting. It would also work! Thanks! I'm surprised MATLAB hasn't added something to make this easier yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you *can* get that information directly from MATLAB, short of printing something with each iteration and counting these lines by hand.

To see why, recall that each `parfor` iteration executes in its own workspace: while incrementing a counter within the loop is legal, accessing its "current" value is not (because this value does not really exist until completion of the loop).  Furthermore, the `parfor` construct does not guarantee any particular execution order, so printing the iterator value isn't helpful.

```
cnt = 0;
parfor i=1:n
    cnt = cnt + 1; % legal
    disp(cnt); % illegal
    disp(i); % legal ofc. but out of order
end
```

Maybe someone does have a clever workaround, but I think that the independent nature of the `parfor` iterations belies taking a reliable count.  The restrictions mentioned above, plus those on using `evalin`, etc. support this conclusion.

As @Jonas suggested, you could obtain the iteration count via side effects occurring outside of MATLAB, e.g. creating empty files in a certain directory and counting them.  This you can do in MATLAB of course:

```
fid = fopen(['countingDir/f' num2str(i)],'w');
fclose(fid);
length(dir('countingDir'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this FEX file: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32101-progress-monitor--progress-bar--that-works-with-parfor

You can easily modify it to return the iteration number instead of displaying a progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

Something like a progress bar could be done similar to this...

Before the `parfor` loop :

```
fprintf('Progress:\n');
fprintf(['\n' repmat('.',1,m) '\n\n']);
```

And during the loop:

```
fprintf('\b|\n');
```

Here we have `m` is the total number of iterations, the `.` shows the total number of iterations and `|` shows the number of iterations completed. The `\n` makes sure the characters are printed in the `parfor` loop.

Answer (score 2):

With Matlab 2017a or later you can use a [data queue](https://se.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel.pool.dataqueue.html) or a [pollable data queue](https://se.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel.pool.pollabledataqueue.html) to achieve this. Here's the MathWorks documentation example of how to do a progress bar from the first link :

```
function a = parforWaitbar

D = parallel.pool.DataQueue;
h = waitbar(0, 'Please wait ...');
afterEach(D, @nUpdateWaitbar);

N = 200;
p = 1;

parfor i = 1:N
    a(i) = max(abs(eig(rand(400))));
    send(D, i);
end

    function nUpdateWaitbar(~)
        waitbar(p/N, h);
        p = p + 1;
    end
end
```

End result :

[image: A picture of the resulting wait bar]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know how much time is left approximately, you can run the program once record the max time and then do this

```
tStart = tic;
parfor i=1:n
  tElapsed = toc(tStart;)
  disp(['Time left in min ~ ', num2str( ( tMax - tElapsed ) / 60 ) ]);
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a utility to do this:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48705-drdan14-parforprogress